# How to split get utf string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, smartfoxserver

```
if (cmd == "card_request") {

   Debug.Log("FOund cards");
   ISFSObject responseParams = (SFSObject)evt.Params["params"];
   Debug.Log(responseParams.GetClass("cards").ToString());
   SFSArray data = (SFSArray)responseParams.GetSFSArray("cards");
   Debug.Log(data.GetUtfString(0));

   //for (int i = 0; i < data.GetUtfString(0).IndexOf("value"); i++) {
     firstSplit = data.GetUtfString(0).Split(';');
     Debug.Log(firstSplit);
   //}
   for (int i = 0; i < firstSplit[0].IndexOf("value"); i++) {
     secondSplit = firstSplit[0].Split(':');
     Debug.Log(secondSplit);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < secondSplit[0].IndexOf("value"); i++) {
     thirdSplit = secondSplit[0].Split(',');
     Debug.Log(thirdSplit);
   }
}
```

the data is coming fine at this line Debug.Log(data.GetUtfString(0)); But when I try to split it it gives errors. Somebody can please suggest me the effective way to split UTF string. Null exceptions occurs at secondSplit and thirdSplit

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I also try this
foreach (string s in data.GetUtfString(0)) {
    firstSplit = s.Split(';');
    Debug.Log(firstSplit);
   }
but then it says can not convert type char to string

Comment: @DavidG: No any error in the above code, but firstSplit getting nothing it is empty, that's why null exceptions occurred at second and third split.

Comment: my problem is that why utf string is not splitting, is there any other method to split the utf strings.

Comment: `Spilt` will only return null if the result of `data.GetUtfString(0)` is also null.

Comment: @DavidG: data.GetUtfString(0) is not null, as it have the value Naja:15,25,36,7,9 I want to split those values, to get numbers 15,25,36,7,9. But it always resturns firstSplit empty.

Comment: Debug.Log(data.GetUtfString(0)); here it shows the value Naja:15,25,36,7,9

Comment: Are you sure that calling `GetUtfString` can be done multiple times?

Comment: In my opinion calling GetUtfString multiple times must not cause any issue. But I am not pretty sure.

Comment: So what do you get if you call it twice, like this? `Debug.Log(data.GetUtfString(0));  Debug.Log(data.GetUtfString(0));`

Comment: I get the same output twice. Naja:30,15,6,7,9 Naja:30,15,6,7,9

Comment: But when I do Debug.Log(data.GetUtfString(0).Split(',')) it returns empty.

Comment: If your log is : System.String[], it doesn't mean its empty, it is a type.

Comment: Yes my log is System.String[] and i resolved the problem now by using 
firstSplit = data.GetUtfString(0).Split(';');
    Debug.Log(firstSplit[0]);

   foreach(string keyValPair in firstSplit)
   {
    string[] tokens = keyValPair.Split(':');
    Debug.Log(tokens[0]);
    foreach(string cardNum in tokens[1].Split(','))
    {
     Debug.Log(cardNum);
    }
   }
Now I can see the result value.